# ChatGPT Answers

Tags: discussion

I've been experimenting with [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/chat) and wondered if it could answer [this question on main.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/85656/80)

So I pasted the whole question text into the ChatGPT interface:

> In MATLAB, I have generated an FIR low pass and high pass filter of
> order 16. The code is as follows:
>
> filter1 = fir1(16,400/16000,'low') %%pass band-400Hz, Sampling
> frequency-16000Hz filter2 = fir1(16,800/16000,'high') %%pass
> band-600Hz, Sampling frequency-16000Hz
>
> The sum of coefficients of low pass filter adds to 1 whereas the sum
> of filter coefficients of high pass filter does not add to 1.
> Shouldn't the sum of filter coefficients add to 1?

and it came up with this response:

> It is not necessarily the case that the sum of the coefficients of an
> FIR filter should add up to 1. In fact, for many types of FIR filters,
> the sum of the coefficients will not be equal to 1.
>
> In the case of the low pass filter you have created using the fir1
> function, the sum of the coefficients does happen to be equal to 1.
> This is because the fir1 function by default uses a windowing
> technique to design the filter, which can cause the sum of the
> coefficients to be equal to 1. However, this is not always the case,
> and it is possible to design FIR filters using fir1 with other
> windowing techniques that do not result in a sum of 1 for the
> coefficients.
>
> For the high pass filter you have created, it is not necessarily the
> case that the sum of the coefficients should be equal to 1. High pass
> filters have a different frequency response than low pass filters, and
> as a result, the coefficients of a high pass filter will typically be
> different from those of a low pass filter. It is possible that the sum
> of the coefficients of your high pass filter does not equal 1, but
> this is not necessarily a problem with your filter design.

[ChatGPT answers on SO have been banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/12570), but I wondered what people think of this specific example?

### My take:

The answer is correct as far as it goes, but it doesn't seem to exhibit any understanding of the deeper details of *why* it's correct. Hardly surprising, given that the machine is a Large Language Model, so I would expect the language to be good but not necessarily an understanding of nuance.

Kinda like some people, really? :-)

Comment: That is not only a meaningless answer, but the few details it gives are wrong. It is a consistent piece of text, and written with conviction, but as an answer here I would downvote it, or at least point out why it’s wrong in a comment.

Comment: @CrisLuengo https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aawB.png I'd think the understanding of words alone would suffice...

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Beautiful!

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Glorious! Thank-you for sharing.

Comment: I wonder if someone is trying to connect ChatGPT to Watson?  Watson doesn't seem to be doing so bad regarding the quality of answers.

Comment: Everyone's talking ChatGPT answers, noone's talking [ChatGPT comments...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiRM9.png) -- also [chess](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnarchyChess/comments/10ydnbb/i_placed_stockfish_white_against_chatgpt_black/)

Answer (score 3):

I broke it

[image]

Comment: WELL DONE!!! :-D That's hilarious.

Comment: uhm, OverLord, the DFT always, ***always*** periodically extends the data passed to it.  The DFT fits $N$ basis functions, all periodic with period $N$, to the data passed to it.  That is operationally equivalent to assuming its input is periodic.

Comment: It's possible, when one party is not completely in command of all of the facts, for the other party to shut them up with a retort that, itself, is fallacious.

Comment: uh, this ain't new? We've been over it. We disagree on whether "assumes input is periodic" is a _fair summary_ statement, not on any substance. I say it's not because it's misleading. Also down arrowing a joke post is a bit stretch, though w/e @robertbristow-johnson

Comment: Specifically, I say "input" is the finite $x$, you say it includes the extension $-\infty$ to $\infty$. I think the statement interprets much more strongly per former, especially to someone who doesn't know better. e.g. if one asks "How long is the input to DFT?", we'll surely answer $N$ ... $\neq \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Quite impressive, yet very prudent

Answer (score 1):

Large language models are capable of convincing writing, with enough trial-and-error - just look at Lambda. I'm unfamiliar with ChatGPT though. Also Lambda's exchange was a social, not technical one, so maybe it won't be as rich... for now.

Curious how they'll perform if tuned directly on Stack Exchange. Also GPT4 in 2023.

**Edit**: so Twitter scooped this thing inside out - a nice overview's in [this YT clip](https://youtu.be/0A8ljAkdFtg), good stuff starts at 16:12. You can run Linux on it...

Comment: Speaking of ChatGPT, I saw this today: https://maximumeffort.substack.com/p/i-taught-chatgpt-to-invent-a-language

Comment: @datageist hmm this makes me realize, these models are _teachable_, even with fixed weights, with prompt engineering. Its responses invoke, effectively, "reason", and per having memory, it builds upon former responses and creates _new_ (to itself) knowledge. I wonder if we can teach it DFT.

Comment: Yeah, I think the memory is one of the new features of ChatGPT (vs GPT-3, etc).